# how to read this Javascript statement

Tags: javascript

I recently came across the following typescript/javascript statment:

```
 expect(h1.innerText).toMatch(/angular 2 app/i, '<h1> should say something about "Angular 2 App"');
```

I cannot get my head around the following part of the statement:

- **/angular 2 app/i**

Since it does not look like a variable, nor it is a string. 
even when I debug this it is not clear to me, what type of object this is.

can anyone explain this to me?

thanks
gerald

Comment: That looks like a regular expression literal to me.

Comment: This is a valid question. Not sure why someone downvoted this. Regular expressions always look weird when you encounter it first time :)

Comment: All the OP needed to do was run `/angular 2 app/i` in the console and it would have told them that it was a RegExp object, and research can go from there. This question is too simple and easy to work out without making a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Regular Expression.  The literal syntax starts and ends with a `/`.  Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).

The following `i` indicates that the match is case insensitive.

The literal syntax: 
`/pattern/flags`
is equivilent to: 
`new RegExp("pattern", "flags");`